# Using Android.IO Outside MainActivity.cs

Tags: android, xamarin, using

OK, apologies up front. I have spent hours trying to figure this out. I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious but I just can't see it.

I'm simply trying to use 
`Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory` but the only place I seem to be able to access `using Android.OS` is in **MainActivity.cs**

What am I missing, why can't I call `Android.OS` elsewhere? global:: doesn't seem to be working either.

Thanks for indulging this basic question..

Comment: are you trying to use if from another class in your Android project?  Or are you trying to use it in a NET Standard library?

Comment: Just other classes within the same Solution. I'm confused why I can't reference Android.OS (or others Android namespaces outside MainActivity.cs).

Comment: a solution can have many projects.  Is this in the same project or not?

Comment: It's a simple cross-platform Xamarin solution that contains 3 projects (cross-platform, and the Android and iOS projects). I can use the Android.OS namespace to access the functions I need in MainActivity.cs to set up a static method to return the path to the SD card. It's not clear how I reference MainActivity from the cross-platform code. Xamarin supports a cross-platform approach to getting paths to internal special folders, it seems complex to need a cross-project approaches to do the same for the SD card. But I am sure I am missing something straightforward.

Comment: I assume I'm going to have to set up a Dependency Service. It just seems so much effort given cross-platform functionality supports getting the path to internal directories.

Comment: iOS doesn't support the concept of SD cards, so providing a cross platform solution to a feature that only exists on one platform doesn't really make sense.  DI is generally the best approach for situations like these.  "so much effort" is relative - it would take ~10 minutes to implement this, probably less time than you have spent on monitoring and updating this post

Comment: Jason - 10 minutes for you but hours of research for me! But it was rewarding, I learnt how to use dependency and have solved the problem. Thank you for taking time to engage on this. Ben

Comment: You can write your solution in the answer and mark it which will help more people with same problem:).